# PHP: str_replace not working

Tags: php

So, I have this code:

```
 <?php
    include '../config.php';
    $query=$_GET['q'];
    //replace
    echo str_replace('\','',$query);

    $sql=mysql_query($query) or die("Query not executed!");
    echo $query;
    echo "\n //executed";

    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

The problem is on $_GET, for example when using *'* , example: "UPDATE users Set coins=3 WHERE username='admin' RETURNS: "update users set coins = 3 where username=**\'admin\'** **=> should be 'admin'** ""

Comment: That is **EXTRAORDINARILY DANGEROUS** code. You are allow users to pass arbitrary SQL into your DB and execute it. What's to stop someone from destroying your DB? Updating their user record and giving themselves total privileges? You should be **THANKFUL** that you're on an outdated PHP install that still has register_globals enabled. Ditch this code, burn it to ashes, scatter the ashes on different continents, then go learn how to write secure PHP code before you do anything else.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a syntax error?

Comment: I don't remember if \ or / that concatenates, but if it's \ you would have to add an extra \ i believe.

Comment: The error is: unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Comment: @MarcB By the look of it, he is testing something, unlikely this is actually in his production.

Comment: No, the error is : T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE_OMG_WHAT_ARE_YOU_DOING_IN_THIS_WAY_ANYONE_CAN_DESTROY_YOUR_DATABASE_YOU_ARE_NOT_SAFE_PLEASE_CHECK_MARK_B_'_S_COMMENT_ABOVE.

Comment: Just testing something people! I KNOW WHAT HAPPENS! Found the solution, adding an extra "\"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'\' is a special character.
Try instead:

```
echo str_replace('\\','',$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string replace, I would suggest you to use String Explode

Syntax: `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`

You can have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)